How can I drag and drop to re-order icons on the Ubuntu dock?
I would like to be able to drag and drop icons in the dock to change their order, but I cannot. When I click and hold on an icon, then move my mouse somewhere else on the dock, a small "+" symbol appears at the base of my cursor and when I release my mouse button it is pinned to the dock.
I am using a new install of Ubuntu 24.04 with the dock as a panel, the applications button at the edge of the panel, and the applications button at the left edge instead of the right. I found some online posts talking about extensions I don't have installed that could cause problems with dragging and dropping, but those were centered around dragging and dropping doing nothing which isn't the same behavior. I also found some remarks about unlocking the dock, but I don't see anywhere to do that in Ubuntu's standard settings or GNOME extension settings and I also don't have a right click menu on the dock.
I'd be open to troubleshooting steps to provide more information if it's needed.

I believe you can only reorder the apps you currently have pinned to the dock. Not the ones that aren't.

That is not correct. You can move/reorder apps and between screens too. Give it a try. Left click with mouse and move left right, up or down.

Indeed, I searched for a long time too!
You must left click on the icon and immediately move it on the dock.
If we wait to move it does not move!
